# How to get an objects dimensions from video

Tags: image-processing, camera

I want to be able to measure an object using the camera on my phone. How would I go about getting an objects width and height from a video? My first thought was some type of 3D tracking of the video. But that's complicated and I would like to make sure i'm on the right track. Basically, what would be the easiest way to go about doing this? OpenCV?

Comment: Well, you would need to know the distance between the object and the camera.  Perhaps you could add a Lidar camera to your phone?  Is there an app for that?

Comment: I need a solution using just the camera alone. That's why I thought the 3D tracking seemed like the way to go.

Comment: You would need at least 2 cameras to do anything 3D, which is why we have 2 eyes instead of one cyclops eye.

Comment: I assumed that by using video and moving the camera around would essentially be doing that.

Comment: If you close one eye and move around, you won't have depth perception...

Comment: That's because you can't really remember the previous images well enough. A computer can